# Wordpress: Custom Post type querying HELP

Tags: wordpress

Alright, The them I am setting up for a client has a left sidebar, content, and right sidebar (using wordpress as a CMS w/o posts). I was going to use custom post types to set some content for the left sidebar, so I have set up in my function.php with:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'about',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'About' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'About' )
      ),
      'public' => true
    )
  );
}

?>
```

Now in my sidebar-left.php I put:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'about', 'posts_per_page' => 1)
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  echo '<div class="entry-content">';
  the_content();
  echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

However,when I do this and refresh the page to test it, I just get a blank page. The page content in the center div is gone, and no information is being pulled from the post. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed a semi colon from the end of

> $args = array( 'post_type' => 'about', 'posts_per_page' => 1)

Perhaps that's why you're getting a blank page. But that might be a typo you've made on here rather than in your code.

Comment: Thanks iamfriendly.. That was part of my mistake. I was also trying to wrap the_content(); in <p></p> ... I just needed to wrap it is echo '<p>'..